# Rewrite Rules, not stopping when rule is matched with [L] if rewritten file is not index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a quite complicated .htaccess file with many RewriteRules so far all have been working well apart from when I try to rewrite to a file that isn't index.php

I have tried adding [L] I'm running it loacally using xampp both index.php and deleteItem.php are valid files. It's also worth noting with my rules I cant point directly to the PHP file anymore.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  #RewriteBase /smartsharing/community/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/members$ index.php?action=members&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/members/$ index.php?action=members&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/members/edit$ index.php?action=editMembers&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/members/edit/$ index.php?action=editMembers&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/edit$ index.php?action=editItems&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/edit/$ index.php?action=editItems&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/([^/]*)/purchasehistory$ index.php?action=purchaseHistory&id=$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/([^/]*)/purchasehistory/$ index.php?action=purchaseHistory&id=$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/([^/]*)/edit$ index.php?action=editItem&id=$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/([^/]*)/edit/$ index.php?action=editItem&id=$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/([^/]*)/remove$ deleteitem.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/([^/]*)/remove/$ deleteitem.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/edit$ index.php?action=edit&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/edit/$ index.php?action=edit&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]+)$ index.php?action=details&id=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/$ index.php?action=details&id=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

My URL is something like http://localhost/smartsharing/community/communityname/items/2/remove

I expect the rewritten URL to be http://localhost/smartsharing/community/deleteItem.php?id=2
but instead it seems to go to
http://localhost/smartsharing/community/index.php?action=details&id=2

Also when posting to http://localhost/smartsharing/community/doAction.php it instead is redirecting to http://localhost/smartsharing/community/index.php?action=details&id=doAction.php

Comment: I personally hate using `.htaccess` for complex things. I'm not very good at it. I redirect EVERY request to `/handle_request.php` (internally), and I have a router which figures out what to do based upon the URL. Not that you should necessarily switch to that way of doing things. But It's what I do. `.htaccess` drives me crazy lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the  `L` it's your rule  `RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]+)$ index.php?action=details&id=$1 [L,QSA]` that caused the problem.

The catch-all pattern `^.*?([^/]+)$`  in your rule matches all rewritten URIs and rewrites them to `/index.php?action=details&id` .

What is happening is that when you go to :

```
/foobar/items/2/remove
```

the following rule is matched

```
RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]*)/items/([^/]*)/remove/$ deleteitem.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Then , to load the destination url `/deleteitem.php?I'd=124` your server again reads your htaccess file and the following rules is matched

```
  RewriteRule ^.*?([^/]+)$ index.php?action=details&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Server continues reading htaccess file until no matching rules are found.

To solve this you can either use `END` flag instead of the `L` replace `L` with `END` in each rules . The `END` flag ensures that the rule is run only ones  in the current rewrite cycle or put a RewriteConds above the rule so it doesn't rewrite existing files or URIs  .

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an explanation into what was happening, your solution worked.